# Why using grep for some netstat commands require sudo priv?

Tags: grep, sudo, netstat, ss

System:

- Ubuntu 20.04.06
- net-tools 2.10-alpha
- grep (GNU grep) 3.4

If I run netstat without sudo I see port information and no process information. This is expected as process information requires elevated privileges.

```
$ netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43445         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41933         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42649         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46059         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45983         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34903         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37257         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37081         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38445         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38335         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350                :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::2377                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5001                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5433                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4789            0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43294           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 :::52206                :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                                -
```

But if I try to send that output to grep I get an error that I need sudo priv. Why? None of the process information was shown on stdout, why would grep change that?

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

**TROUBLESHOOTING:**

- This does not happen if I dont include `-p` (i.e. `netstat -tuln | grep 8080`)
- This does not happen if I use smaller grep string (i.e. `netstat -tulpn | grep 8`)
- Using `ss` does not show the same problem (i.e. `ss -tulpn | grep 8080`)

What is going on here?

Note: Yes I know netstat is deprecated and I should use `ss` instead, I am just curious why this behavior is happening.

Comment: If you run `netstat -tulpn >/dev/null` you get the error?

Comment: Yes I do. Same error.

Comment: If you run `netstat -tulpn | grep xyzzy` (for some impossible value `xyzzy`) do you still get the error?

Comment: Finally, if you run `netstat -tulpn | grep 8080 >/tmp/8080.list` (a) do you get the error (b) does the file `/tmp/8080.list` contain any lines?

Comment: What do you get with `netstat --version`

Answer (score 2):

Very likely you always get this message, but *when* you get the message changes.

The message is being sent to stderr, bypassing grep.  So there is a bit of a race condition as to when you see it.

Likely netstat prints it right after options parsing before printing any data. If grep starts printing data right away, the message will be mixed in with the other output and you might miss it or it might end up printed over.  If grep takes a moment, then the message might show up at the start of the output.

Without the buffering and random delays that pipes cause, the message should always be at the beginning.

If you want to ignore the message, you could try

```
netstat -tulpn 2> /dev/null | grep 8080
```

If you wanted the message to always be filtered by grep, you could try (for newer shells like bash)

```
netstat -tulpn /dev/null |& grep 8080
```

or equivalently (for all shells)

```
netstat -tulpn 2&>1 | grep 8080
```

Note that if you pipe the original command to a pager, the stderr output will also bypass the pager, and might be seen briefly, but the pager is pretty much guaranteed to print over it and/or wipe it out.

Comment: _"Likely netstat prints it right after options parsing before printing any data. If grep starts printing data right away, the message will be mixed in with the other output"_ -- I don't see how this follows as `grep` can't really print anything before `netstat` outputs something on stdout.

Comment: Once you involve a pipe in this, the timing between stderr and stdout are disconnected and there's no guarantee which one will get there first.  That is what it means to be a race condition.  Order of events is not preserved and we don't know who will win the race.

Comment: I am not following. From your logic, if I dont use a pipe to grep, then I should see that error every time, is that true? But I don't as you can see from the output above without grep.

Comment: When I run it, I always see that output, with or without grep.  Unless, of course, it scrolls off my screen and I miss it or the pager covers it up, etc.   You already stated you get it with `netstat -tulpn  > /dev/null ` so I have to assume you get it without the redirect, you just can't see it for some reason.

Comment: @user10489, If stderr goes directly to the terminal, and the message there is printed first, then I don't see how the message to stdout, that both is printed later and goes through the pipe could come _earlier_. How would adding the new step of a pipe and `grep` make the data going that way come out _faster_? It's different if both stdout and stderr are connected via pipes to other processes, since in that case the scheduling between those processes would matter, and that scheduling may be arbitrary (or close enough that it doesn't matter)

Comment: What part of "race conditions make things unpredictable" do you not get?  Anyway, maybe you should be focusing on where the output went and what it's hiding under rather than when.

Answer (score -2):

As you've pointed out, `netstat` needs to run as root to display certain pieces of information. `grep` does not require special privileges to read from a pipe. So,

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```

Without root privileges the `-p` flag will always trigger the warning when instructed to display details about processes you don't own. Perhaps you missed seeing the message (especially if you piped the result from `grep` into a pager such as `less` that controls the output as full screen and doesn't cater for messages written to *stderr*).

Comment: I already knew this and explained it in my post. Also that does not explain why `netstat -tulpn | grep 8` works and `netstat -tulpn | grep 8080` does not work. My question is why the odd behavior I found from my troubleshooting.

Comment: @Dave `netstat -tulpn | grep 8080` works, but returns nothing since there is no occurrence of `8080` in the netstat output. The real question is why the warning about root is missing when you run `netstat -p` **without** grep (since AFAIK it goes to stderr and should be visible in the terminal regardless of where stdout is piped).

Comment: @steeldriver indeed. Comments added to the question to try and ascertain the environment